# How to know the percentage of time increase between 2 hours with moment. js or pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I'd like to know what % of time has been increased by 2 hours.

I have a code that serves to find the percentage over 100 since the beginning of the day, but I don't know how it could be done in 2 hours.

To calculate the percentage of time for 24 hours from a given hour with these two javascript code options works well for me.

```
var time_begin = '08:00:00';       
var a = time_begin.split(':');
var seconds = (+a[0]) * 60 * 60 + (+a[1]) * 60 + (+a[2]);
var start_time = Math.round((seconds/(24*60*60))*100);
```

and

```
var now = new Date(...);
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getTime());
startOfDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
var percent = (now.getTime()-startOfDay.getTime()) / (1000*60*60*24)
```

But I don't want to know how long it's been 24 hours. What I want is to know the percentage of increase or decrease time between 2 hours.

% incrementally

```
var originalTime = 13:22:15
var durationToincrease = 00:18:09
var finalDuration = 13:40:24
```

The increased % is: xx%.

or % decreasing

```
var originalTime = 13:05:01
var durationToincrease = 00:14:09
var finalDuration = 12:50:52
```

The decreased % is: xx%.

Thank you very much for the help, I could do it in pure javascript or with the javascript library if possible moment. js or other.

A greeting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code relies on being able to convert a timestamp to seconds. You can do that independently of `Date` objects if you have the time as a string:

```
function timestamp_to_seconds(timestamp) {
    var [hours, minutes, seconds] = timestamp.split(':').map((t) => parseInt(t, 10));
    return seconds + 60 * minutes + 60 * 60 * hours;
}
```

Once you have all of the information, it's pretty easy to figure out the ratios:

```
var original_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds('13:22:15');
var duration_seconds = timestamp_to_seconds('00:18:09');
var new_seconds = original_seconds + duration_seconds;

var ratio = new_seconds / original_seconds;
```

`ratio - 1` is the percent increase (or decrease) from `original_seconds` to `new_seconds`.